# Não consigo Carregar nenhuma Dll em c/c++

Tags: c, dll

Estou tentando carregar uma dll para um projeto. Estou usando linguagem c e pretendo utilizar GTK para fazer o design, estou usando também o console MSYS para compilar meu projeto. Porém, preciso carregar uma dll, e não consigo carregar nem a dll que preciso e nem nenhuma outra dll.
Segue o meu código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    HINSTANCE hinstlib;

    hinstlib = LoadLibrary(TEXT("./MinhaDll.dll"));

    if(hinstlib == NULL){
        printf("erro");

        return -1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

estou usando a seguinte linha de comando para compilar meu código:

gcc meucoddigo.c -o codigo `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

a dll está no local certo e não importa qual dll eu tente carregar o console sempre imprime "erro". Já tentei criar um arquivo usando fopen e escrever nesse arquivo usando fprintf e o arquivo foi criado no local certo, por isso acredito que o problema não seja a forma com que estou escrevendo o local da dll na função LoadLibrary.

Caso alguém possa ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o erro. A biblioteca carrega e executa sem problemas. 
Se você colocar o código-fonte (ou um exemplo) do conteúdo da **MinhaDll**, as versões do compilador, msys, Windows, etc., talvez seja mais fácil responder.

Comment: Algumas dicas: *1)* ao imprimir o "erro", chame a funcao 
[GetLastError()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror)
e consulte o código que está retornando; *2)* Se a dll está no mesmo local do exe, não 
coloque o path, e no windows sempre use o separador \ , nunca o `./` ; *3)* na linha 
de comando do gcc, os arquivos **\*.c** devem estar no final do comando seguido das libs 
(ex: **-lxyz**); e *4)* tente fazer a carga da biblioteca funcionar antes de carregar o 
GTK.

Comment: Usando GetLastError obtive o erro 193. Estou usando MSYS2 64bit, gcc 10.3.0 e windows 10 home 64 bit. Infelizmente não posso passar informações sobre a dll mas o fato é que eu não estou conseguindo abrir se quer uma dll qualquer que seja.

Comment: Você tem certeza que a DLL é **64** bits e o arquivo não está corrompido? O teste que fiz foi com o mesmo compilador (10.3.0). O erro 193 indica que o formato do arquivo da DLL é inválido.

Comment: Olha me desculpa a minha ignorância sobre o assunto, mas eu não tenho certeza se a dll é 64 bits. Supondo que não seja, você consegue me indicar uma maneira da abrir essa dll?

Comment: Eu consegui resolver o problema aqui. Instalei a versão para 32 bit e funcionou

Answer (score -1):

O problema era que eu precisava usar uma versão 32 bits do MSY2.